# Xcode issue: how to copy paste with storyboard IBOutlet

Tags: macos, xcode

After I updated my Xcode , I can not do copy paste with storyboard IBOutlet.

I have to type by hand every time.

Very annoying.

[image: 0]

I tried on two Mac , both are Xcode 10.1 on Mac OS 10.14.2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using "Right Click" with "Paste" option.

Working on Xcode 10

[image]